# How to write a Elastic Search Query(DSL) for search using multiple fields?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation, elasticsearch-dsl, elasticsearch-dsl-py

I want to write an Elastic Search DSL query, where i want to display results based on input  on multiple fields by a user. The user is a candidate , who is searching for a job, The job fields include fields like Job_Title, Skills, Experience, Education etc.

Comment: did you get a chance to look into my answer?

Answer (score 1):

you can use [multi_match](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html) query for your use-case.